# Not able plot a line over a box-plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, plot, boxplot

I am drawing a box-plot so I use the following code in MATLAB. I am very new to matlab.

```
for k=1:N    % running through k categories in the plot 
  patch(...);   % The box 

  % now drawing the whiskers and percentiles 
  line(...); % the median
  line(..); % the 25th percentile 
  line(..); % the 75th percentile
  line(...); % the max
  line(..); % the min 
end

% THIS LINE ONLY IS DISPLAYED NOT THE BOX-PLOT, WHY?? 
% A poly-line passing median of each box 
plot([1:N]-0.5, Ys, '-Xr', 'LineWidth', 4, 'MarkerSize', 12);
```

The line drawn in the final statement only gets displayed, not the box-plot When I comment out the `plot` statement, then the box-plot is displayed.

But, how can I have them displayed one on top of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this will work as I have never used box plots, but to prevent multiple plots getting overwritten on a figure you usually use `hold on` command. Try adding the line `hold on` just before your final plot statement